# Html export table selected rows to pdf

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table generated dynamically with php like:

```
I'd   Sr.No.  Name  Date
1    1001    Vijay    2018-01-01  []
2    1004    Abc      2018-01-01  []
3    1007    Xyz       2018-01-01  []
```

It contains about 50 rows. I have a checkbox at each row.

- I want to select some rows from table and export them to pdf.
- l tried jquery datatable pdf export but that option is not much customizable and for less column data pdf is not aligned center.
- I can also try server side with php with TCPDF or mPdf which are highly customizable. But then I have to send all selected  rows text to server side.

So what is best option here.

- send text to server and use TCPDF or mPdf
- Or is there any js library that can do my task

Comment: There are other js option: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MladenIlić, how to create full width table spread over full width of pdf in jsPDF.